# Background service on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, background-process

Is it possible to create a background service with the current Ubuntu SDK?

Its hard to find any information apart from couple of conversations on some mailing lists.

Greetings Ben

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to write background services. You need to use the provided Ubuntu services.

This is often raised as a blocker to writing apps, e.g. https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg15883.html